# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement in VB.net project for student into

Tags: vb.net

i recieve that error but i dont know how to fix, im a student in programming so please help me out, here is my code.
Im trying to make a student info for our project

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data

Public Class Form3

    Dim provider As String
    Dim datafile As String
    Dim connstring As String
    Dim connection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection

    Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'ProjectDataSet.Student_Info' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Student_InfoTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ProjectDataSet.Student_Info)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
        datafile = "D:\Jaja Files\Programming files\Project.mdb"
        connstring = provider & datafile
        connection.ConnectionString = connstring
        connection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "Insert into Student Info([Student ID#],[Given Name],[Surname],[Course],[Year],[Age],[Address],[Contact No],[Email])" + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, connection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Student ID#", CType(TextBox1.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Given Name", CType(TextBox3.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Surname", CType(TextBox2.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Course", CType(ComboBox1.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Year", CType(ComboBox2.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Age", CType(TextBox4.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Address", CType(TextBox5.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Contact No", CType(TextBox6.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Email", CType(TextBox7.Text, String)))

        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            connection.Close()
            TextBox1.Clear()
            TextBox2.Clear()
            TextBox3.Clear()
            ComboBox1.ResetText()
            ComboBox2.ResetText()
            TextBox4.Clear()
            TextBox5.Clear()
            TextBox6.Clear()
            TextBox7.Clear()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

        StudentInfoBindingSource.EndEdit()
        StudentInfoBindingSource.AddNew()
        Student_InfoTableAdapter.Update(ProjectDataSet.Student_Info)
        MessageBox.Show("Ok Prof!")


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        StudentInfoBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Me.Hide()
        Form4.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

i already tried some but still i dont understand how those works,

Comment: Do you know why those brackets are required around some of those column names?  It's because of the spaces and other special characters.  They aren't required on, for instance, `Surname`.  That applies to any identifiers, including your table name.

Comment: will try it now, and will update

Comment: @jmcilhinney i tried but still got the issue

Comment: "Insert into Student Info([Student ID#],[Given Name], Surname, Course, Year, Age, Address,[Contact No], Email)" + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

Comment: `[Student Info]`. Try not to use spaces when assigning names to fields. Note that Parameters' values are assigned in the `VALUES` side. Meaning, possibly don't use the same name for a parameter and a field. Maybe, something like: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentId", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = TextBox1.Text`. No need to cast `TextBox.Text` to string: it's already a string.

Comment: do i need to remove the New OleDbParameter?

Comment: Tried what?  We have no idea whether what you tried should have worked if we don;t know what you tried.  Many people have said that they tried something and it turned out to be the wrong thing so it's not safe for us to assume.

Comment: On an unrelated note, what's the point of concatenating two literal `Strings`?  Would you use `1 + 1` where you need the value `2`?  I would think not.

Comment: Also, what's the point of using `CType` to convert all those `Strings` to `Strings`?  The `Text` of a `TextBox` is already a `String` so there's no conversion necessary.  What you should be doing is converting the `Strings` you already have for `Age` and `Year` to numbers, because they should be numerical data types in the database so you should be saving numbers to them.

Comment: Do yourself, and everyone that you'll work with in the future a favor: Don't ever put spaces in the name of a database object, be it a table, a column, or a view. Ever. Just don't. There really is no reason to do so. StudentInfo should suffice as a table name. StudentId should be sufficient as the column name, as GivenName, and SurName. If you really feel the need for a space, use an underscore: Student_Info, Student_ID, Given_Name, etc.